# Javascript: how to manipulate a generated string ( from .net) with sepical chars to be redable by javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, string, escaping

I have a `.net (VB)` method that generate a string that may or may not contains a chars that eventually makes javascript generates an error on execution 

e.g.:
`generated string`

```
JSFunctionName('ab''c
st''h
s'th--+
sth+'
sth'
)
```

how to let it like this, with escaping from `'` and other `special chars` that may comes

```
JSFunctionName('ab''cst''hs'th--+sth+'sth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1

I came across a built-in .NET function that does that (maybe framework 4!?) I can't find it anymore that's a shame. I needed this too.

But I eventually found a function written by the always excellent Rick Strahl:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/114530.aspx

That is what you need..